# Best Static Photo Gallery Generator

Tags: static, image-gallery, photo-gallery

There are a lot of static website generators out there, but most of them seem rather text-oriented (to my knowledge). What are the best **image gallery static website generators?**

( Note: I realize that a more general form of this question [has been already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186290/best-static-website-generator). I think this question is different enough to stand on its own. )

Comment: More specific question on [softwarerecs.se]: [Generate static picture gallery website with image captions from EXIF tags](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11135/60)

Answer (score 25):

You definitely want to check [sigal](http://sigal.saimon.org) ([demo](http://saimon.org/sigal-demo/galleria/)). It is the cutest generator I've tried so far. It's also the most recent and up-to-date (inspired by pelican, the popular static blog engine - now powering [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/pelican.html)).

There is an extensive list [here](http://www.nico.schottelius.org/docs/static-image-gallery-generator-comparison/). Lazygal would be my second choice.

Answer (score 24):

A relatively unknown gallery generator aimed mainly at photos can be [fgallery](http://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/fgallery/) ([demo here](http://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/fgallery/demo/)). JavaScript only, but very stylish and simple. Doesn't support separate albums.

Answer (score 6):

[llgal](https://github.com/bgoglin/llgal) turns a folder of images into a simple gallery site with one simple command: `llgal`.

It's very tweakable.

Some basic options to get started:

- `--title "My Holiday Pictures"` sets the gallery title to "My Holiday Pictures".
- `--sx 800` and `--sy 800` scales the each framed image to max 800 height or max 800 width, and links to the full image.

Putting it all together:

```
llgal --title "My Holiday Pictures" --sx 800 --sy 800
```

and you're done!

Comment: Updated link here https://github.com/bgoglin/llgal

Answer (score 4):

I found [jAlbum](http://jalbum.net/en/software/features) to be quite nice. It allows to create static galleries, and users can pick between different skins (or create their own). jAlbum is written in Java and is available for [download](http://jalbum.net/en/software/download/current) for a variety of platforms.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since I used it, but I found [BINS](http://freshmeat.net/projects/bins/) did just what I wanted. Not sure if it's still maintained.

Comment: Looks dead. Link is to freshmeat/freecode that links to http://bins.sautret.org/ which is an empty page with title "default". Going up a domain serves a frame enclosing http://jerome.sautret.free.fr/perso which no longer exists.